# Chip Identification in Push Button Toy

Tags: hardware, embedded, integrated-circuit

I have a toy that simply consists of a button which plays a variety of phrases when activated. My intention is to replace the sounds with my own. However, I have been unable to identify the chip and therefore cannot interface with it.

Here is a picture and schematic of the board, developed using a multimeter in continuity mode.
[image: circuit board]
[image: board schematic]

Here is a closeup of the chip.
[image: chip]

I believe the markings are as follows:

```
JFK8-4
P04003
```

There is also a "triforce" logo, for a company which I have not identified yet.

Pins 1 and 8 are particularly interesting, as they are not connected to anything. I assume they were used to program the chip, but am not able to identify a protocol if any exists.

It would be appreciated if anyone can locate a datasheet. I would also be happy with advice on identifying the function of the unconnected pins.

Comment: A single chip solution strongly suggests that the samples are in mask ROM and not something you're going to be able to change.  You're better off *replacing* the module with something you can customize.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Well that's a shame, I don't have the facilities to do such a thing. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Sure you do - find some other gadget, module, or DIY solution which can have the sound files changed, and stuff it back into the toy.  Recordable greeting cards are a thing, you can do things with a small MCU and a flash chip, etc...

Answer (score 2):

It is from this family. The pinout may vary slightly:

http://en.waytronic1999.com/m/ProductsStd_171.html

http://n.waytronic1999.com/m/ProductsStd_115_00100.html

---

In short:
you can change the sounds if you just buy a new chip. it will be cheaper.
Or a new toy that can not only play but also record sounds.

recordable sound chips:

https://www.alibaba.com/showroom/postcard-recordable-sound-chips.html

https://www.alibaba.com/showroom/sound-chip-for-postcard.html

Answer (score 1):

I am working on the same project right now. Just buy one of these:
https://wiki.dfrobot.com/DFPlayer_Mini_SKU_DFR0299

Dfb mini mp3 player costs 3bucks
And you can load some aufio files via a sdcard